# Storing environment variables and secrets on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, next.js13, production-environment

I have a next.js app which I deployed on EC2. I wish to add some api keys and secrets. I've added some in the next.config.js file but it seems that didn't work.

Here is my next.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL: 'https://djangobackend.com/api/articles/',
    NEXT_PUBLIC_COMMENT_URL: 'https://djangobackend.com/api/articles/comment/create/',
    NEXT_PUBLIC_COMMENT_LIST_URL: 'https://djangobackend.com/api/articles/comment/',
    NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTACT_URL: 'https://djangobackend.com/contact/',
},
}
```

I acceess it in my code this way:

```
const regURL = processs.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL
```

What is the best approach to store this variables and other sensitive secrets in EC2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned some secrets available in **next.config.js** file so I am assuming this file is version controlled in github/bitbucket etc. This is *very bad practice*. We should never ever put secrets in code. In AWS you can use either **Secrets Manager** or **SSM Parameter Store** service for storing sensitive data. In your code you just need to mention secret name and build it and in runtime secrets will be available